# i want to take the text a user has entered and print it to the screen, appending each new thing they say

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a chat system. So when a user types what they want to say, it's printed to the chat. but I need to know how to keep appending to this chat?? 
here's the outline so far:

```
<textarea name="chat" id="chat" placeholder="Comment text." rows="2" 
cols="35" required></textarea><br><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">send</button>

<p id="theChat"></p>



<script>
var textareaValue = document.getElementById('chat').value

var chatArray = [];
document.getElementById("theChat").innerHTML = chatArray;

function myFunction() {
  chatArray.unshift(textareaValue);
  document.getElementById("theChat").innerHTML = chatArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to append to the existing text:

```
document.getElementById("theChat").innerHTML = document.getElementById("theChat").innerHTML + chatArray;
```

Do take some time to look into concatenating strings as that might help your development in future.

Comment: this seems to be working but the array just outputs ",,,,,," anytime I send what I've typed

Comment: You need to extract the individual strings from your array - looks like you might be appending the actual array object when you'll need to append the individual elements one-by-one.